Elementor + Phlox Pro + Wordpress Problem by update
The problem occurred by updating the Phlox Pro Theme I think. The website won't show correctly. Elementor doesnt work in the editor mode.
I tried pretty much everything, like reinstalling etc but no success. Then activated the logs.
The log:
[21-Nov-2024 12:25:30 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function auxin_kses() in /www/htdocs/w01b33af/homepage.de/wp-content/plugins/auxin-elements/includes/elements/image.php:563
Stack trace:
#0 /www/htdocs/w01b33af/homepage.de/wp-content/plugins/auxin-elements/includes/elementor/widgets/image.php(729): auxin_widget_image_callback(Array)
#1 /www/htdocs/w01b33af/homepage.de/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php(2325): Auxin\Plugin\CoreElements\Elementor\Elements\Image->render()
#2 /www/htdocs/w01b33af/homepage.de/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/widget-base.php(635): Elementor\Controls_Stack->render_by_mode()
#3 /www/htdocs/w01b33af/homepage.de/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/widget-base.php(776): Elementor\Widget_Base->render_content()
#4 /www/htdocs/w01b33af/homepage.de/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/element-base.php(483): Elementor\Widget_Base->print_content()
#5 /www/htdocs/w01b33af/homepage.de/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/element-base.php(144 in /www/htdocs/w01b33af/homepage.de/wp-content/plugins/auxin-elements/includes/elements/image.php on line 563

The error is coming from the "Shortcodes and extra features for Phlox theme" plugin, which I guess it's an add-on for the Phlox Pro theme you're using. From what I can see in their support forum it seems that this plugin has been sort of abandoned by Averta, so your options are: a) hire a developer and ask them to fix this plugin for you; or -my recommendation- b) switch to a different theme, and uninstall this plugin from your site as it seems to have a few security vulnerabilities.

A new Phlox version is available 2.17.0 (17.12.2024). Compatibility fixes for Elementor v3.26 have been applied. Follow these instructions to upgrade and fix the problem you are having.

The error occurs due to incompatibility with version 3.26.0 of Elementor Free. The solution is to revert to a previous version using Elementor’s tools: Elementor → Tools → Version Control, and roll back to version 3.25.11 or earlier.
